# Help me with be + adj/ verb grammar in the below sentences

Tags: grammar, sentence-meaning, adjectives

I know how to use passive grammar but here I'm confused with the use of be + adj.

Is there any differences in the meaning of below sentences?

> You can cook cauliflower until it **is soft**. (is + adj)
>
>  
> You can cook cauliflower until it **is softened** (is + PP - passive sentence)

> When the cooking **is complete**. (is + adj)
>
>  
> When the cooking **is completed** (is + PP - passive sentence)

> The database update process **is now complete**. (is + adj)
>
>  
> The database update process **is now completed** (is + PP - passive sentence)

Answer (score 1):

#### Example 1

"...until it is soft." indicates a final state to achieve. "...until it is softened" indicates a change, but leaves unstated how much change, that is just how much softer must the  become. Also, I think most fluent speakers would be more likely to say:

> You can cook cauliflower until it **has** softened.

This third form is describing the process from the PoV of its completion.

None of these three forms uses the passive voice. In each case the main verb is "cook". The object of "cook" is "cauliflower" and it is the object that receives the action of the verb.A sentence such as:

> Cauliflower is cooked by heating it until it is soft.

would be in the passive voice, and here there would be little difference in meaning or effect. All four forms are natural and valid.

#### Example 2

> When the cooking is complete ...

is not a sentence, it is a clause. so is

> When the cooking is completed ...

Neither is in the passive voice. The difference is one of style. One could also write "has been completed" and that would not be in the passive voice either.

#### Example 3

> - The database update process is now complete.
> - The database update process is now completed.
> - The database update process has now been completed.

All three are in the passive voice. There is little if any difference in meaning, it is again a matter of style. All are valid and a fluent speaker might say any of them.